# TrigMath, 2 masses, rigid rod computing velocity

Tags: c, math, trigonometry, game-physics, gravity

Like everyone else, I am doing a Thrust clone just to brush up. I have arrived at the stage where the ship picks up the pod.

Essentially I have two masses (consider centre of sphere only) connected with a rigid, massless rod. L never changes, doesn't break.

[image: balls!]

In this case, the ship(ma) has mass 1.0, and the pod(mb) has mass 2.0. What is the math required to compute new positions? When I apply thrust to the ship(ma), how do I apply that to pod(mb)? (and make it swing around as expected)  Doing the ship itself was straight forward, usual velx-=sin(angle)*thrust, vely+=cos(angle)*thrust. posx+=velx. etc. I know I used to know how to do this, but school was soo many years ago.

Comment: Heh odd, I skimmed through a reply, but saved it until tv was done, but now it is missing. Deleted?

Comment: Deleted because I found a mistake, and it was too late for me to fix it.  I'll add a correct answer now.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think my biggest issue was that I kept thinking of the ship as the primary actor (since it is until we get to the pod). But upon connecting to the pod, I should switch from tracking the ship's position, to tracking the center-of-mass of the 2-mass object. The apply thrust to its center (split between movement and spining based on the angular differences of ship direction, and rod's angle). Placing the ball and ship is then just a function of drawing them at the correct place. I believe I have enough to go on now, thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches for you.

The first is simpler.  Relax rigidity.  Make the bar that joins the two be a spring.  The equal and opposite force it exerts on both of them is proportional to the amount its length has been displaced.  If you make the spring very rigid, you'll have an almost rigid bar very simply.

The second is to make the bar actually rigid.  In this case the entire system can be described by the position and velocity of the center of mass, and the angle and rate of rotation of the whole system.  The center of mass is the weighted average of the positions of the points in the system times the mass at that point.  In your case it will be a point 2/3 of the way along the bar towards the pod.  (Because the pod weighs twice what the ship does.)  No matter where you are pushing, the center of mass will move as if you pushed right at the center of mass, so you already know how to move the center of mass.

Now you have to consider the rate of rotation.  When you apply a force at the ship, a fraction of it is at right angles to the bar.  That fraction, in addition to moving the center of mass, is making the system spin.  That portion of the force is accelerating the ship but not the pod.  Apply the force to the ship, and you can figure out the rate of acceleration.  The center of mass is accelerating at 1/3 the rate that ship is.  So from the point of view of the center of mass, 2/3 of the sideways acceleration of the ship is going into making the system spin.  Divide 2/3 by the distance from the center of gravity to the ship, and you have the angular acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest to code by splitting the rotational part from the translational part.

You have a sum of forces applied to ball A - e.g. gravity force + thrust from engine + friction force.  Let this be **FA** (a vector).
You have a sum of forces applied to ball B - e.g. gravity force + friction force.  Let this be **FB** (a vector).

The center of mass of the object is located on the rod.  It is at location (ma **A** + mb **B**) / (ma+mb).  It is distance ca from mass A where ca = mb/(ma+mb).|**AB**| and distance cb from mass B where cb = ma/(ma+mb).|**AB**|.  Let **U** be the normalized version of **AB** (i.e. **U** has unit length).

Model the system so that you have the location of the center of mass = **X** and an angle theta.  You also store the velocity **V** and the rotational velocity w.  We wish to find the linear acceleration **A** and the rotational acceleration w'.

The movement of the center of mass is governed by Newton's law using the TOTAL force on the system and the TOTAL mass, so:

**FA** + **FB** = (ma + mb).**A**

The rotation is governed by the torques involved.  (scalar) Torque = **force** x **vector from center of mass**.  The torque on each object is therefore:

TA = **FA** x ca.- **U**

TB = **FB** x cb.**U**

Note that this is the 2D cross-product i.e. TA = **FA**[x] * ca.- **U**[y] - **FA**[y] * ca.- **U**[x]

The moment of inertia is defined as

I = ca*ca*ma + cb*cb*mb

Then

TA + TB = I.w'

Derivation of the location of each mass given **X** and theta is left as an exercise for the reader :)